# AnimationFrame Misunderstanding

Tags: javascript, animation

So I'm trying to build a multiplayer web game and I'm almost finished however I was adding in some extra features like splash screens and whatnot when I noticed something weird. If I comment out section 01 entirely then this code still works however if I comment out the second line in section 02, regardless of whether or not section 01 is commented out, then it will NOT work. I probably have a misunderstanding of what the animationFrame is doing or/and how it works. Can someone explain this to me or provide a link to an explanation. Thank You!

```
//----------START SECTION 01----------
window.requestAnimationFrame = (function() {
    return window.requestAnimationFrame ||
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame  ||
    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame     ||
    function(callback) {
      window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
    };
})();
//----------END SECTION 01----------

//----------START SECTION 02----------
(function animationLoop() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animationLoop);
    gameLoop();
})();
//----------END SECTION 02----------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shim that you assigned to window.requestAnimationFrame is a poly-fill for older browsers, but if the browser you are testing in all ready has requestAnimationFrame then of course it will still work in that browser when you comment it out.

Of course you need to always call requestAnimationFrame becuase it is kindof a replacment for setTimeout. If you don't call it then gameLoop will only run once.